# CoreLocation User Speed

Tags: swift

I currently am trying to get the current user's device movement speed. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let manager = CLLocationManager()
var currentSpeed = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print(manager.location?.speed)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

the only issue is that it prints `"Optional(-1,0)"`

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Location will give you a negative value for speed if the device isn't moving, or is moving slowly enough that the math doesn't make sense.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed