# location manager not able to get speed in ios

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager in my iOS app to get user's current location.

I also need to calculate the speed of the user and I got that, it can be calculated using the delegate method "didUpdateLocations".

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    var speed1 = location.speed
    speedLabel.text = "\(speed1)"
}
```

I can get the update of user's current location but the speed value is not correct. Initially the value of speed is -1 then no change in the value even the location is updating correctly.

The initialization of my location manager is below

```
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

What's wrong with it.

Advanced thanks..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872002/5501940

Comment: It is the default behavior and you have to handle that on your own. There are many filtering mechanisms to override this issue like kalman filter.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when dealing with external events and accessories (location, hardware communications etc.) Apple will give you a -1 when the information you want is not computable or is somehow invalid.  You cannot make any assumptions, you simply need to intercept that information (computation error of some kind) and deal with it as if the information was missing.

> A negative value indicates an invalid speed

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423798-speed